# How do I change the position of this sliding text-area?

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

I'm trying to add a disclaimer section to the website I'm working on. I want a tab-like button at the bottom of every page which would open up a text area.

I searched codepen.io a bit and found a very simple way to do it. After removing non-relevant syntax, I tried to move the tab from the top of the page to the bottom.

Here's where I came across a problem. When the tab was at the top of the page, the text area would push down the tab when clicking on it.

Now that it's at the bottom, the textarea shows up above the tab, as the tab itselfs stays at the bottom of the page.

**How do I make sure the text area pops up beneath the tab, pushing the tab up?**

```js
$(document).on('click', '#menu-tab', function() {
  $('#menu-nav').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
}
#menu-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#menu-tab {
  background-color: #FC4349;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0% 45% 0% 45%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
#menu-nav {
  display: none;
  background-color: #FC4349;
  margin: 0% 30% 0% 30%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="menu-wrapper">
    <div id="menu-nav">disclaimertextdisclaimertextdisclaimertext
      <br>disclaimertextdisclaimertextdisclaimertext</div>
    <div id="menu-tab" class="closed">Disclaimer</div>
  </div>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
</body>
```

In case my description didn't give a clear image of the situation:

**Tab at the top the of screen**
[image: Tab at the top the of screen]

**Tab at the bottom of the screen**
[image: Tab at the bottom of the screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the html containing the disclaimer to below the tab

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/28dawctg/))

```html
<div id="menu-wrapper">
  <div id="menu-tab" class="closed">Disclaimer</div>
  <div id="menu-nav">disclaimertextdisclaimertextdisclaimertext
    <br>disclaimertextdisclaimertextdisclaimertext</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That did it! Can't believe I didn't think of that... Thank you :)